# When did data install/upgrade scripts get introduced

Tags: module, installation, setup, magento-1.5

What version of Magento first allowed data install/setup scripts i.e. `mymodule/data/mymodule_setup...`

It looks like in 1.5 CE data scripts do not work - but a cursory look at the core resource setup class i can see references to them?

I am wondering when they were introduced and from what version they can be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see what is happening now.

pre 1.6 the data install scripts were mixed with the sql install scripts under the sql directory.

1.6 and up is what i am used to where the data and sql directories are separate.

Answer (score 2):

The `data_version` column was added in [version 1.4](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.4/app/code/core/Mage/Core/sql/core_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.8.20-0.8.21.php). 
The code to apply all data updates was also added in [version 1.4](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.4/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php). Look for the line `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllDataUpdates();`. This line is missing in the same file in [version 1.3](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.3/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php).
The strange thing is that for example the `data` folder in `Mage_Catalog` was added in the version 1.6. Maybe it wasn't functional until 1.6.

For more info on magento versions visit https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror

Comment: Yes that seems to be the case as i am on a 1.5 CE install and the data insalls are not being picked up - but everything suggests its should be.